# Asp.Net MVC Custom Validation Attribute With StructureMap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have a custom attribute in asp.net mvc and use structure map.
how can I inject ContextDB into the custom ValidationAttribute?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ContextDB _Context { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings(_Context);

        // Checking...

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

my code doesn't work, _Context is null.
what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have registered your DI to MVC you could use MVC's dependency resolver everywhere.

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     private ContextDB _context { get; set; }

     public CustomValidationAttribute()
     {
         // assuming you have a IContextDB interface which mapped to 
         // ContextDB in your StructureMap
          _context =DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContextDB>();
     }
     // rest of your code
}
```

For more advanced scenario look at Setter Injection concept also.